# Tomcat 7.0.54 JVM crashed

Tags: java, tomcat

My Tomcat 7.0.54 has crashed with the report below.

The crash seems to be with zip.dll. However, there are some suggestions that I should disable to compression in server.xml. Unfortunately, my Tomcat has already been disabled for the compression.

I couldn't find any other references anywhere with this issue.

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00000000731437cc, pid=4140, tid=4276
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_67-b01) (build 1.7.0_67-b01)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.65-b04 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [zip.dll+0x37cc]
#
# Core dump written. Default location: D:\xxxxx\x123\xxxxxEE201311\Server\tomcat-7.0.54\tanuki\bin\hs_err_pid4140.mdmp
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x0000000044ce0000):  JavaThread "http-bio-18070-exec-58" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=4276, stack(0x0000000054130000,0x0000000054230000)]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, reading address 0x0000000000000018

Registers:
RAX=0x0000000000000000, RBX=0x0000000000000295, RCX=0x0000000047695c20, RDX=0x0000000000000000
RSP=0x000000005422c460, RBP=0x0000000044ce01e8, RSI=0x0000000047695c20, RDI=0x0000000000000000
R8 =0x0000000000000298, R9 =0x000000005422c540, R10=0x000000000126ffcf, R11=0x0000000324050318
R12=0x000000005422e5d8, R13=0x000000037d104ed8, R14=0x000000005422e5f0, R15=0x0000000044ce0000
RIP=0x00000000731437cc, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010206

Top of Stack: (sp=0x000000005422c460)
0x000000005422c460:   0000000048670170 000000006c325932
0x000000005422c470:   0000000000000001 000000006c3257e7
0x000000005422c480:   0000000000000000 00000000731421c3
0x000000005422c490:   0000000000000295 0000000044ce01e8
0x000000005422c4a0:   0000000047695c20 000000006c3de19f
0x000000005422c4b0:   0000000700000295 0000000000000000
0x000000005422c4c0:   0000000000000001 0000000043592bb0
0x000000005422c4d0:   0000000000000000 000000006c50c0df
0x000000005422c4e0:   000000005422c530 000000006c324b52
0x000000005422c4f0:   000000007a8c115e 0000000000000000
0x000000005422c500:   0000000044ce01e8 000000006c507d8b
0x000000005422c510:   0000000000000002 0000000000000002
0x000000005422c520:   0000000000000002 0000000000000000
0x000000005422c530:   000000005422cc00 0000000001f186d8
0x000000005422c540:   0000000001f18110 0000000000000000
0x000000005422c550:   0000000000000036 000000005422cc00 

Instructions: (pc=0x00000000731437cc)
0x00000000731437ac:   00 48 8b 5c 24 70 48 83 c4 50 5f c3 48 89 5c 24
0x00000000731437bc:   08 48 89 6c 24 10 48 89 74 24 18 57 48 83 ec 20
0x00000000731437cc:   4c 8b 52 18 49 8b e9 49 8b f0 48 8b d9 4d 85 d2
0x00000000731437dc:   75 04 4c 8b 52 10 48 83 61 50 00 4d 85 c0 78 72 


Register to memory mapping:

RAX=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
RBX=0x0000000000000295 is an unknown value
RCX=0x0000000047695c20 is an unknown value
RDX=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
RSP=0x000000005422c460 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x0000000044ce0000
RBP=0x0000000044ce01e8 is an unknown value
RSI=0x0000000047695c20 is an unknown value
RDI=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R8 =0x0000000000000298 is an unknown value
R9 =0x000000005422c540 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x0000000044ce0000
R10=0x000000000126ffcf is at entry_point+111 in (nmethod*)0x000000000126fdd0
R11=0x0000000324050318 is an oop
java.util.zip.ZipFile 
 - klass: 'java/util/zip/ZipFile'
R12=0x000000005422e5d8 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x0000000044ce0000
R13=0x000000037d104ed8 is an oop
java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInflaterInputStream 
 - klass: 'java/util/zip/ZipFile$ZipFileInflaterInputStream'
R14=0x000000005422e5f0 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x0000000044ce0000
R15=0x0000000044ce0000 is a thread


Stack: [0x0000000054130000,0x0000000054230000],  sp=0x000000005422c460,  free space=1009k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [zip.dll+0x37cc]

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
J 317  java.util.zip.ZipFile.read(JJJ[BII)I (0 bytes) @ 0x000000000126ffcf [0x000000000126ff60+0x6f]
J 306 C2 java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInputStream.read([BII)I (125 bytes) @ 0x00000000012a5dd4 [0x00000000012a5ce0+0xf4]
J 386 C2 java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read([BII)I (138 bytes) @ 0x000000000124f4fc [0x000000000124f1e0+0x31c]
J 7127 C2 org.apache.felix.framework.util.WeakZipFileFactory$WeakZipFile$WeakZipInputStream.read([BII)I (64 bytes) @ 0x00000000026d5198 [0x00000000026d5120+0x78]
J 4797 C2 org.apache.wicket.util.io.Streams.copy(Ljava/io/InputStream;Ljava/io/OutputStream;I)I (60 bytes) @ 0x0000000001fa1078 [0x0000000001fa0fc0+0xb8]
J 5804 C2 nl.xxxxx.hera.PnAbstractResource$1.writeData(Lorg/apache/wicket/request/resource/IResource$Attributes;)V (59 bytes) @ 0x00000000022aa378 [0x00000000022aa240+0x138]
J 5557 C2 org.apache.wicket.request.resource.AbstractResource.respond(Lorg/apache/wicket/request/resource/IResource$Attributes;)V (110 bytes) @ 0x0000000002210cec [0x00000000022108a0+0x44c]
J 6171 C2 org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle$HandlerExecutor.respond(Lorg/apache/wicket/request/IRequestHandler;)V (43 bytes) @ 0x000000000209799c [0x0000000002097700+0x29c]
J 6228 C2 org.apache.wicket.request.RequestHandlerStack.execute(Lorg/apache/wicket/request/IRequestHandler;)V (171 bytes) @ 0x00000000023d3164 [0x00000000023d2cc0+0x4a4]
J 6251 C2 org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.execute(Lorg/apache/wicket/request/IRequestHandler;)V (61 bytes) @ 0x00000000023dae70 [0x00000000023daca0+0x1d0]
J 6253 C2 org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequestAndDetach()Z (21 bytes) @ 0x00000000023d799c [0x00000000023d77e0+0x1bc]
J 5734 C2 org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequest(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;Ljavax/servlet/FilterChain;)Z (473 bytes) @ 0x00000000022741e8 [0x0000000002273720+0xac8]
J 5392 C2 org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;Ljavax/servlet/FilterChain;)V (9 bytes) @ 0x0000000002164214 [0x00000000021641e0+0x34]
J 2162 C2 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V (624 bytes) @ 0x000000000165a2bc [0x0000000001659dc0+0x4fc]
J 4591 C2 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Request;Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Response;)V (1416 bytes) @ 0x0000000001f4b314 [0x0000000001f4b0a0+0x274]
J 2226 C2 org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Request;Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Response;)V (917 bytes) @ 0x0000000001834f3c [0x0000000001832440+0x2afc]
J 4457 C2 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Request;Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Response;)V (364 bytes) @ 0x0000000001edf7ac [0x0000000001edf2e0+0x4cc]
J 3141 C2 org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn.invoke(Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Request;Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Response;)V (471 bytes) @ 0x0000000001ac36f4 [0x0000000001ac3300+0x3f4]
J 4498 C2 org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(Lorg/apache/coyote/Request;Lorg/apache/coyote/Response;)V (586 bytes) @ 0x0000000001f0e32c [0x0000000001f0dcc0+0x66c]
J 4529 C2 org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(Lorg/apache/tomcat/util/net/SocketWrapper;)Lorg/apache/tomcat/util/net/AbstractEndpoint$Handler$SocketState; (1124 bytes) @ 0x0000000001f2dcbc [0x0000000001f2d8a0+0x41c]
J 4563 C2 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(Lorg/apache/tomcat/util/net/SocketWrapper;Lorg/apache/tomcat/util/net/SocketStatus;)Lorg/apache/tomcat/util/net/AbstractEndpoint$Handler$SocketState; (738 bytes) @ 0x0000000001f3c8dc [0x0000000001f3c5e0+0x2fc]
J 4466 C2 org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run()V (608 bytes) @ 0x0000000001ee4b24 [0x0000000001ee49e0+0x144]
J 4571% C2 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Ljava/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker;)V (225 bytes) @ 0x0000000001d7940c [0x0000000001d79060+0x3ac]
j  java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run()V+5
j  org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run()V+4
j  java.lang.Thread.run()V+11
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x0000000047982800 JavaThread "Wicket-PageSavingThread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3868, stack(0x0000000060970000,0x0000000060a70000)]
  0x0000000047981000 JavaThread "Wicket-PageSavingThread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4216, stack(0x0000000060850000,0x0000000060950000)]
  0x0000000047980800 JavaThread "WicketFsCleanup" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3688, stack(0x0000000060650000,0x0000000060750000)]
  0x000000004797f800 JavaThread "http-bio-18070-exec-200" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4600, stack(0x0000000060400000,0x0000000060500000)]
  0x000000004797f000 JavaThread "http-bio-18070-exec-199" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=460, stack(0x00000000602b0000,0x00000000603b0000)]
  0x000000004797e000 JavaThread "http-bio-18070-exec-198" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5056, stack(0x0000000060140000,0x0000000060240000)]
  0x000000004797d800 JavaThread "http-bio-18070-exec-197" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4728, stack(0x000000005ff70000,0x0000000060070000)]
  0x00000000439aa000 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3760, stack(0x0000000043c90000,0x0000000043d90000)]
  0x00000000439a4000 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3984, stack(0x0000000041a40000,0x0000000041b40000)]

Other Threads:
  0x00000000439a3000 VMThread [stack: 0x0000000043b60000,0x0000000043c60000] [id=2692]
  0x0000000044a34000 WatcherThread [stack: 0x00000000463d0000,0x00000000464d0000] [id=3788]

VM state:at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread:  ([mutex/lock_event])
[0x0000000000de8e80] Safepoint_lock - owner thread: 0x00000000439a3000
[0x0000000000de8f00] Threads_lock - owner thread: 0x00000000439a3000

Heap
 garbage-first heap   total 20971520K, used 11942959K [0x00000002f0000000, 0x00000007f0000000, 0x00000007f0000000)
  region size 8192K, 552 young (4521984K), 19 survivors (155648K)
 compacting perm gen  total 106496K, used 101980K [0x00000007f0000000, 0x00000007f6800000, 0x0000000800000000)
   the space 106496K,  95% used [0x00000007f0000000, 0x00000007f6397250, 0x00000007f6397400, 0x00000007f6800000)
No shared spaces configured.

Heap Regions: (Y=young(eden), SU=young(survivor), HS=humongous(starts), HC=humongous(continues), CS=collection set, F=free, TS=gc time stamp, PTAMS=previous top-at-mark-start, NTAMS=next top-at-mark-start)
            TS     0 PTAMS 0x00000002f07fffd0 NTAMS 0x00000002f07fffd0 space 8192K,  99% used [0x00000002f0000000, 0x00000002f07fffd0, 0x00000002f0800000)
            TS     0 PTAMS 0x00000002f0fde758 NTAMS 0x00000002f0fde758 space 8192K,  98% used [0x00000002f0800000, 0x00000002f0fde758, 0x00000002f1000000)
            TS     0 PTAMS 0x00000002f17fffd8 NTAMS 0x00000002f17fffd8 space 8192K,  99% used [0x00000002f1000000, 0x00000002f17fffd8, 0x00000002f1800000)
            TS     0 PTAMS 0x00000002f1fffff8 NTAMS 0x00000002f1fffff8 space 8192K,  99% used [0x00000002f1800000, 0x00000002f1fffff8, 0x00000002f2000000)
            TS     0 PTAMS 0x00000002f2422360 NTAMS 0x00000002f2422360 space 8192K,  51% used [0x00000002f2000000, 0x00000002f2422360, 0x00000002f2800000)
 HS         TS     9 PTAMS 0x00000002f2800000 NTAMS 0x00000002f2800000 space 8192K,  61% used [0x00000002f2800000, 0x00000002f2cf4130, 0x00000002f3000000)
            TS     0 PTAMS 0x00000002f3800000 NTAMS 0x00000002f3800000 space 8192K, 100% used [0x00000002f3000000, 0x00000002f3800000, 0x00000002f3800000)
 HS         TS     1 PTAMS 0x00000002f3800000 NTAMS 0x00000002f3800000 space 8192K,  61% used [0x00000002f3800000, 0x00000002f3cf4130, 0x00000002f4000000)
 HS         TS    17 PTAMS 0x00000002f4000000 NTAMS 0x00000002f4000000 space 8192K,  61% used [0x00000002f4000000, 0x00000002f44f4130, 0x00000002f4800000)
            TS     3 PTAMS 0x00000002f4800000 NTAMS 0x00000002f4800000 space 8192K, 100% used [0x00000002f4800000, 0x00000002f5000000, 0x00000002f5000000)
 HS         TS    31 PTAMS 0x00000002f5000000 NTAMS 0x00000002f5000000 space 8192K,  61% used [0x00000002f5000000, 0x00000002f54f4130, 0x00000002f5800000)
          F TS    45 PTAMS 0x00000002f5800000 NTAMS 0x00000002f5800000 space 8192K,   0% used [0x00000002f5800000, 0x00000002f5800000, 0x00000002f6000000)
 HS         TS    17 PTAMS 0x00000002f6000000 NTAMS 0x00000002f6000000 space 8192K,  61% used [0x00000002f6000000, 0x00000002f64f4130, 0x00000002f6800000)
    CS Y    TS    47 PTAMS 0x00000002f6800000 NTAMS 0x00000002f6800000 space 8192K, 100% used [0x00000002f6800000, 0x00000002f7000000, 0x00000002f7000000)
 HS         TS     5 PTAMS 0x00000002f7000000 NTAMS 0x00000002f7000000 space 8192K,  61% used [0x00000002f7000000, 0x00000002f74f4130, 0x00000002f7800000)
 HS         TS    27 PTAMS 0x00000002f7800000 NTAMS 0x00000002f7800000 space 8192K,  61% used [0x00000002f7800000, 0x00000002f7cf4130, 0x00000002f8000000)
          F TS    45 PTAMS 0x00000002f8000000 NTAMS 0x00000002f8000000 space 8192K,   0% used [0x00000002f8000000, 0x00000002f8000000, 0x00000002f8800000)
 HS         TS    23 PTAMS 0x00000002f8800000 NTAMS 0x00000002f8800000 space 8192K,  61% used [0x00000002f8800000, 0x00000002f8cf4130, 0x00000002f9000000)
    CS Y    TS    47 PTAMS 0x00000002f9000000 NTAMS 0x00000002f9000000 space 8192K, 100% used [0x00000002f9000000, 0x00000002f9800000, 0x00000002f9800000)
 HS         TS    13 PTAMS 0x00000002f9800000 NTAMS 0x00000002f9800000 space 8192K,  61% used [0x00000002f9800000, 0x00000002f9cf4130, 0x00000002fa000000)
 HS         TS     9 PTAMS 0x00000002fa000000 NTAMS 0x00000002fa000000 space 8192K,  61% used [0x00000002fa000000, 0x00000002fa4f4130, 0x00000002fa800000)
 HS         TS     0 PTAMS 0x00000002fa800000 NTAMS 0x00000002fa800000 space 8192K,  61% used [0x00000002fa800000, 0x00000002facf4130, 0x00000002fb000000)
    CS Y    TS    47 PTAMS 0x00000002fb000000 NTAMS 0x00000002fb000000 space 8192K, 100% used [0x00000002fb000000, 0x00000002fb800000, 0x00000002fb800000)
    CS Y    TS    47 PTAMS 0x00000002fb800000 NTAMS 0x00000002fb800000 space 8192K, 100% used [0x00000002fb800000, 0x00000002fc000000, 0x00000002fc000000)
 HS         TS    39 PTAMS 0x00000002fc000000 NTAMS 0x00000002fc000000 space 8192K,  61% used [0x00000002fc000000, 0x00000002fc4f4130, 0x00000002fc800000)
          F TS    45 PTAMS 0x00000002fc800000 NTAMS 0x00000002fc800000 space 8192K,   0% used [0x00000002fc800000, 0x00000002fc800000, 0x00000002fd000000)
    CS Y    TS    47 PTAMS 0x00000002fd000000 NTAMS 0x00000002fd000000 space 8192K, 100% used [0x00000002fd000000, 0x00000002fd800000, 0x00000002fd800000)
          F TS     0 PTAMS 0x00000007ee000000 NTAMS 0x00000007ee000000 space 8192K,   0% used [0x00000007ee000000, 0x00000007ee000000, 0x00000007ee800000)
          F TS     0 PTAMS 0x00000007ee800000 NTAMS 0x00000007ee800000 space 8192K,   0% used [0x00000007ee800000, 0x00000007ee800000, 0x00000007ef000000)
          F TS     0 PTAMS 0x00000007ef000000 NTAMS 0x00000007ef000000 space 8192K,   0% used [0x00000007ef000000, 0x00000007ef000000, 0x00000007ef800000)
          F TS     0 PTAMS 0x00000007ef800000 NTAMS 0x00000007ef800000 space 8192K,   0% used [0x00000007ef800000, 0x00000007ef800000, 0x00000007f0000000)

Card table byte_map: [0x0000000006180000,0x0000000008a10000] byte_map_base: 0x0000000004a00000

Polling page: 0x0000000000820000

Code Cache  [0x0000000001130000, 0x00000000029c0000, 0x0000000004130000)
 total_blobs=7897 nmethods=7369 adapters=478 free_code_cache=24353Kb largest_free_block=24592384

Compilation events (10 events):
Event: 5149.769 Thread 0x00000000439d0800 7897             java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap::values (27 bytes)
Event: 5149.772 Thread 0x00000000439d0800 nmethod 7897 0x00000000029aea10 code [0x00000000029aeb60, 0x00000000029aed98]
Event: 5151.135 Thread 0x00000000439cc800 7898             java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap::ensureSegment (144 bytes)
Event: 5151.144 Thread 0x00000000439cc800 nmethod 7898 0x00000000029afd50 code [0x00000000029afec0, 0x00000000029b04b8]
Event: 5177.276 Thread 0x00000000439d0800 7899   !         sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor112::invoke (61 bytes)
Event: 5177.278 Thread 0x00000000439d0800 nmethod 7899 0x00000000029ae6d0 code [0x00000000029ae820, 0x00000000029ae8f8]
Event: 5183.096 Thread 0x00000000439cc800 7900             org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WebApplication::getAndRemoveBufferedResponse (31 bytes)
Event: 5183.110 Thread 0x00000000439cc800 nmethod 7900 0x000000000298ef90 code [0x000000000298f160, 0x000000000298fcb0]
Event: 5279.756 Thread 0x00000000439d0800 7901             org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession::setId (55 bytes)
Event: 5279.771 Thread 0x00000000439d0800 nmethod 7901 0x000000000298df50 code [0x000000000298e100, 0x000000000298e900]

GC Heap History (10 events):
Event: 5273.122 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=516 (full 8):
 garbage-first heap   total 20971520K, used 8394346K [0x00000002f0000000, 0x00000007f0000000, 0x00000007f0000000)
  region size 8192K, 231 young (1892352K), 33 survivors (270336K)
 compacting perm gen  total 106496K, used 101976K [0x00000007f0000000, 0x00000007f6800000, 0x0000000800000000)
   the space 106496K,  95% used [0x00000007f0000000, 0x00000007f6396130, 0x00000007f6396200, 0x00000007f6800000)
No shared spaces configured.
Event: 5273.281 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=517 (full 8):
 garbage-first heap   total 20971520K, used 6730020K [0x00000002f0000000, 0x00000007f0000000, 0x00000007f0000000)
  region size 8192K, 17 young (139264K), 17 survivors (139264K)
 compacting perm gen  total 106496K, used 101976K [0x00000007f0000000, 0x00000007f6800000, 0x0000000800000000)
   the space 106496K,  95% used [0x00000007f0000000, 0x00000007f6396130, 0x00000007f6396200, 0x00000007f6800000)
No shared spaces configured.
}
Event: 5294.595 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=517 (full 8):
 garbage-first heap   total 20971520K, used 17498257K [0x00000002f0000000, 0x00000007f0000000, 0x00000007f0000000)
  region size 8192K, 1303 young (10674176K), 17 survivors (139264K)
 compacting perm gen  total 106496K, used 101976K [0x00000007f0000000, 0x00000007f6800000, 0x0000000800000000)
   the space 106496K,  95% used [0x00000007f0000000, 0x00000007f6396338, 0x00000007f6396400, 0x00000007f6800000)
No shared spaces configured.
Event: 5335.134 Thread 0x00000000478d8800 Threw 0x000000038e4ee018 at C:\re\jdk7u67\1368\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1244
Event: 5335.134 Thread 0x00000000478d8800 Threw 0x000000038e4ef0c8 at C:\re\jdk7u67\1368\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1244
Event: 5335.135 Thread 0x00000000478d8800 Threw 0x000000038e4f3460 at C:\re\jdk7u67\1368\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1244

Events (10 events):
Event: 5335.132 loading class 0x000000004786de20
Event: 5335.132 loading class 0x000000004786de20 done
Event: 5335.132 loading class 0x0000000049c584a0
Event: 5335.132 loading class 0x0000000049c584a0 done
Event: 5335.133 loading class 0x000000004786e620
Event: 5335.133 loading class 0x000000004786e620 done
Event: 5335.134 loading class 0x0000000049242a50
Event: 5335.134 loading class 0x0000000049242a50 done
Event: 5335.135 loading class 0x00000000456dae80
Event: 5335.135 loading class 0x00000000456dae80 done


Dynamic libraries:
0x000000013f740000 - 0x000000013f773000     D:\xxxxx\x123\xxxxxEE201311\Server\jdk-1.7.0_67\bin\java.exe
0x0000000076d50000 - 0x0000000076ef9000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
0x0000000076b30000 - 0x0000000076c4f000     C:\Windows\system32\kernel32.dll
0x000007fefcc60000 - 0x000007fefcccc000     C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
0x000007fefdcc0000 - 0x000007fefdd9b000     C:\Windows\system32\ADVAPI32.dll
0x000007fefd7a0000 - 0x000007fefd83f000     C:\Windows\system32\msvcrt.dll
0x000007fefd780000 - 0x000007fefd79f000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\sechost.dll
0x000007fefd960000 - 0x000007fefda8d000     C:\Windows\system32\RPCRT4.dll
0x0000000076c50000 - 0x0000000076d4a000     C:\Windows\system32\USER32.dll
0x000007fefcf50000 - 0x000007fefcfb7000     C:\Windows\system32\GDI32.dll
0x000007fefcf20000 - 0x000007fefcf2e000     C:\Windows\system32\LPK.dll
0x000007fefeb30000 - 0x000007fefebf9000     C:\Windows\system32\USP10.dll
0x000007fefb570000 - 0x000007fefb764000     C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.7601.17514_none_fa396087175ac9ac\COMCTL32.dll
0x000007fefd700000 - 0x000007fefd771000     C:\Windows\system32\SHLWAPI.dll
0x000007fefd930000 - 0x000007fefd95e000     C:\Windows\system32\IMM32.DLL
0x000007fefdbb0000 - 0x000007fefdcb9000     C:\Windows\system32\MSCTF.dll
0x000000006ee70000 - 0x000000006ef42000     D:\xxxxx\x123\xxxxxEE201311\Server\jdk-1.7.0_67\jre\bin\msvcr100.dll
0x000000006c310000 - 0x000000006cae2000     D:\xxxxx\x123\xxxxxEE201311\Server\jdk-1.7.0_67\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll
0x000007fef7750000 - 0x000007fef7759000     C:\Windows\system32\WSOCK32.dll
0x000007fefd840000 - 0x000007fefd88d000     C:\Windows\system32\WS2_32.dll
0x000007fefec00000 - 0x000007fefec08000     C:\Windows\system32\NSI.dll
0x000007fef7ef0000 - 0x000007fef7f2b000     C:\Windows\system32\WINMM.dll
0x0000000076f10000 - 0x0000000076f17000     C:\Windows\system32\PSAPI.DLL
0x0000000074190000 - 0x000000007419f000     D:\xxxxx\x123\xxxxxEE201311\Server\jdk-1.7.0_67\jre\bin\verify.dll
0x0000000073100000 - 0x0000000073128000     D:\xxxxx\x123\xxxxxEE201311\Server\jdk-1.7.0_67\jre\bin\java.dll
0x0000000073140000 - 0x0000000073155000     D:\xxxxx\x123\xxxxxEE201311\Server\jdk-1.7.0_67\jre\bin\zip.dll
0x000007fefdda0000 - 0x000007fefeb28000     C:\Windows\system32\SHELL32.dll
0x000007fefedf0000 - 0x000007fefeff3000     C:\Windows\system32\ole32.dll
0x00000000730d0000 - 0x00000000730e9000     D:\xxxxx\x123\xxxxxEE201311\Server\jdk-1.7.0_67\jre\bin\net.dll
0x000007fefc300000 - 0x000007fefc355000     C:\Windows\system32\mswsock.dll
0x000007fefc2f0000 - 0x000007fefc2f7000     C:\Windows\System32\wship6.dll
0x00000000730b0000 - 0x00000000730c1000     D:\xxxxx\x123\xxxxxEE201311\Server\jdk-1.7.0_67\jre\bin\nio.dll
0x0000000073130000 - 0x000000007313b000     D:\xxxxx\x123\xxxxxEE201311\Server\jdk-1.7.0_67\jre\bin\management.dll
0x000007fefb550000 - 0x000007fefb565000     C:\Windows\system32\NLAapi.dll
0x000007fef7710000 - 0x000007fef7725000     C:\Windows\system32\napinsp.dll
0x000007fefc180000 - 0x000007fefc1db000     C:\Windows\system32\DNSAPI.dll
0x000007fef7740000 - 0x000007fef774b000     C:\Windows\System32\winrnr.dll
0x000007fefbd00000 - 0x000007fefbd07000     C:\Windows\System32\wshtcpip.dll
0x000007fefa390000 - 0x000007fefa3b7000     C:\Windows\system32\IPHLPAPI.DLL
0x000007fefa380000 - 0x000007fefa38b000     C:\Windows\system32\WINNSI.DLL
0x000007fef82d0000 - 0x000007fef82d8000     C:\Windows\system32\rasadhlp.dll
0x000007fefa220000 - 0x000007fefa273000     C:\Windows\System32\fwpuclnt.dll
0x000007fefc360000 - 0x000007fefc377000     C:\Windows\system32\CRYPTSP.dll
0x000007fefc060000 - 0x000007fefc0a7000     C:\Windows\system32\rsaenh.dll
0x000007fefcb60000 - 0x000007fefcb6f000     C:\Windows\system32\profapi.dll
0x000007fefc9c0000 - 0x000007fefc9cf000     C:\Windows\system32\CRYPTBASE.dll
0x000007fefa1b0000 - 0x000007fefa1c1000     C:\Windows\system32\dhcpcsvc6.DLL
0x000007fefa130000 - 0x000007fefa148000     C:\Windows\system32\dhcpcsvc.DLL
0x0000000180000000 - 0x0000000180059000     D:\xxxxx\x123\xxxxxEE201311\Server\tomcat-7.0.54\tanuki\lib\wrapper.dll
0x0000000073080000 - 0x00000000730a4000     D:\xxxxx\x123\xxxxxEE201311\Server\jdk-1.7.0_67\jre\bin\sunec.dll
0x0000000074200000 - 0x000000007420b000     D:\xxxxx\x123\xxxxxEE201311\Server\jdk-1.7.0_67\jre\bin\sunmscapi.dll
0x000007fefccf0000 - 0x000007fefce5c000     C:\Windows\system32\CRYPT32.dll
0x000007fefcb70000 - 0x000007fefcb7f000     C:\Windows\system32\MSASN1.dll
0x000000006eb30000 - 0x000000006ecc5000     D:\xxxxx\x123\xxxxxEE201311\Server\jdk-1.7.0_67\jre\bin\awt.dll
0x000007fefcfc0000 - 0x000007fefd097000     C:\Windows\system32\OLEAUT32.dll
0x000007fefa800000 - 0x000007fefa818000     C:\Windows\system32\DWMAPI.DLL
0x000007fef67c0000 - 0x000007fef68e5000     C:\Windows\system32\DBGHELP.DLL

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=../../endorsed -Dcatalina.base=../.. -Dcatalina.home=../.. -Djava.io.tmpdir=../../temp -Djava.security.auth.login.config=../../conf/jaas.config -DJNDIFILE=../../conf/jndi.properties -Djava.awt.headless=true -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=D:\xxxxx\x123\xxxxxEE201311\Server\jdk-1.7.0_67/cacerts -Dorg.jboss.security.SecurityAssociation.ThreadLocal=true -da -Djava.util.logging.config.file=${catalina.home}\conf\logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Djdk.util.TimeZone.allowSetDefault=true -Dxxxxx.bundles=../../bundles -DCSSFILE=../../conf/pss-login.css -Dxxxxx.config=../../conf -Dxxxxx.web2.disableCSRFprevention=true -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1666 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -XX:+UseG1GC -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252 -Duser.language=en -Xms20480m -Xmx20480m -Djava.library.path=../lib -Dwrapper.key=P02UyD3GH-O9hum9O0Zx2XE9ZwNwOuCs -Dwrapper.port=32000 -Dwrapper.jvm.port.min=31000 -Dwrapper.jvm.port.max=31999 -Dwrapper.pid=4616 -Dwrapper.version=3.5.20-st -Dwrapper.native_library=wrapper -Dwrapper.arch=x86 -Dwrapper.service=TRUE -Dwrapper.cpu.timeout=10 -Dwrapper.jvmid=3 -Dwrapper.lang.domain=wrapper 
java_command: org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

Environment Variables:
JAVA_HOME=D:\xxxxx\x123\xxxxxEE201311\Server\jdk-1.7.0_67
PATH=C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Dell\SysMgt\oma\bin;C:\Program Files\Dell\SysMgt\shared\bin;C:\Program Files\Dell\SysMgt\RAC5;
USERNAME=NL-DEVS90$
OS=Windows_NT
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 23 Stepping 6, GenuineIntel



---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS: Windows Server 2008 R2 , 64 bit Build 7601 Service Pack 1

CPU:total 8 (4 cores per cpu, 1 threads per core) family 6 model 23 stepping 6, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, tsc

Memory: 4k page, physical 33549248k(7015276k free), swap 67096632k(42024308k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.65-b04) for windows-amd64 JRE (1.7.0_67-b01), built on Jul 25 2014 08:55:00 by "java_re" with unknown MS VC++:1600

time: Thu Oct 16 23:00:08 2014
elapsed time: 5451 seconds
```

Comment: happened to me a number of times, just restarted it. The issue is probably at their end and this is why they want you to submit the report if you are interested.

Comment: did you tried compression using Apache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed it looks like a problem with decompression of your input. Possibly you're receiving a corrupt message.

`zip.dll` is part of your Java installation, could be a problem with that although unlikely.

It's not "tomcat compression" that's the culprit here, but Wicket. Not sure how you configure compression there but you should look there if you want to turn it off.